# I forgot my password

Tags: parity-signer

I forgot my password and also my private key, but i have my keystore and also the address.
Please help me.

Comment: You could try bruteforcing the encrypted keystore file to recover your plaintext private key. But that depends on how long/complex your password was

Comment: Sir plz how can take my password plz help plz

Answer (score -1, accepted):

install ethereum wallet on you'r PC and do this steps 
To backup your wallet you will need to make a copy of the key file(s) located in your ethereum directory.

Linux: ~/.ethereum/keystore
Mac: /Library/Ethereum/keystore
Windows: %APPDATA%/Ethereum
The file should look something like this:

UTC--2015-09-18T14-07-57.023663538Z--da78c8721e4ede42cf488304551eb596dd5f93e23

Comment: I don't think this addresses the original question; it does not deal with Parity, restoring existing accounts, or missing passwords for private keys. It is, however, a valid way of locating the keystore for back up purposes (which the OP already has) for `geth`.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read the question well